# I'm trying to change the color of a clock on my website. My code is not working and I'm wondering what mistake I made

Tags: javascript, colors, clock

This code should display the time, in red if it is after 8:00 at night in the Central time zone, and in green if it is after 7:30 a.m.  Unfortunately, this is my first time with Javascript and I'm apparently making some mistake.  Nothing is displayed.  Can anyone help me find the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var centralDate = getOffsetDate(360);

function getOffsetDate(offsetInMintues) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() - offsetInMintues);
  return d;
}

function GetClock(){
d = getOffsetDate();
nhour  = d.getHours();
nmin   = d.getMinutes();
     if(nhour ==  0) {ap = " AM";nhour = 12;} 
else if(nhour <= 11) {ap = " AM";} 
else if(nhour == 12) {ap = " PM";} 
else if(nhour >= 13) {ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;}

if(nmin <= 9) {nmin = "0" +nmin;}

var h = centralDate.getHours();
var m = centralDate.getMinutes(); 
if (h >= 20 || 
  h <7 ||
  (h == 7 && m <= 30)) {
  c="#FF0000"
}
else {c=#00FF00"}

document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+nhour+":"+nmin+ap+"";
setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);

}

<FONT COLOR=c>;
window.onload=GetClock;
</FONT>
</script>
<div id="clockbox"></div>
```

Comment: Well, you're missing a quote around your color in the `else` statement, for one thing.

Comment: And it looks like you're missing a set of `ap` somewhere. Then it's a matter of fixing your `NaN`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing anything into `getOffsetDate()` inside `GetClock`, which hoses up all the numeric calculations.

(Plus the stuff I mentioned in my comments.)

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/W7YcM/)

(The `setTimeout` is commented out for my sanity.)

You don't actually *change* the color anywhere, either; you just set a value, then never do anything else again.

Plus you have HTML inside your `<script>` tags, which doesn't work. Rather change the `<font>` tag attribute... although nobody actually uses font tags anymore now that we know CSS, so you'll probably want to do that instead for your own sake.

(I'm not actually sure you want to call `getOffsetDate()` from `GetClock`, but it's not clear to me what you're trying to do, so I don't know. In the fiddle I left it as-is and pass in a 0-minute offset.)

Answer (score 0):

You should write the last five lines like:

```
$("<div id='clockbox'></div>").css("color", "red").appendTo("body");
```

P. S. If this code is unfamiliar to you, let me tell you that this is jQuery, a popular JavaScript library. You can download it from jQuery.com an include it in your page like any other JavaScript file.